# ScatterLayout is overlapping buttons

Tags: kivy

My ScatterLayout (its area) is still overlapping buttons, so the buttons are inactive until I move or scale Scatterlayout. When I move it one button becomes active and the other becomes inactive, so it's uncomfortable for the user.

Here is the code:

```
class MyScatter(ScatterLayout):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<MyScatter>:
    scale: 1
    do_scale: True 
    do_translation: True
    do_rotation: False

    Image:
        id: img
        source: 'img.png'
        size_hint: (0.43, 0.6)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.33, 'center_y': 0.5}
        keep_ratio: True
''')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        mainbox = FloatLayout()
        mainbox.add_widget(Button(text="Fwd",
                                  font_size="17dp",
                                  size_hint=(.075, .15),
                                  pos_hint={"left":1,
                                            "center_y":0.5},
                                  on_press=self.forward))

        self.ms = MyScatter()
        mainbox.add_widget(self.ms)
        ...
```

Can I limit the ScatterLayout (its area) to be the same as the area of the image?

Comment: Please post a minimal runnable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but is this what you want?

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('modules', 'showborder', '')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory as F


class MyScatter(F.Scatter):
    pass


Builder.load_string('''
<MyScatter>:
    scale: 1
    do_scale: True 
    do_translation: True
    do_rotation: False
    size_hint: None, None
    size: img.size
    auto_bring_to_front: False
    Image:
        id: img
        source: 'data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png'
        # size_hint: (0.43, 0.6)
        # pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.33, 'center_y': 0.5}
        keep_ratio: True
        size: self.texture.size if self.texture else (0, 0)
''')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        mainbox = F.FloatLayout()
        self.ms = MyScatter()
        mainbox.add_widget(self.ms)
        mainbox.add_widget(F.Button(text="Fwd",
                                  font_size="17dp",
                                  size_hint=(.075, .15),
                                  pos_hint={"left":1,
                                            "center_y":0.5},
                                  on_press=print))

        return mainbox


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: The initial position and size of the image should be preserved. (size_hint: (0.43, 0.6)
pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.33, 'center_y': 0.5} . And what is the advantage of using Factory?

Comment: Actually, `auto_bring_to_front` solved my problem of overlapping buttons.

Comment: nice, glad to hear that.